# How to find an absolute path to DLL registered in registry with C++?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, registry

I'm trying to diagnose a case when some executable doesn't run from a startup.

First, i want to check whether the `filename.exe` of exists on the disk (*i.e.* it wasn't deleted).

The input I have is the file name of the executable and its UUID.

**Question:** Having those inputs, how can I check the registry if it is registered and if so, what is the path of the executable?

Comment: What do you mean by "some executable DLL"? DLLs are *loaded*, not *executed*.

Comment: @Johnsyweb-Thanks for your comment. I'm sorry that my terminology is not so accurate. The executable dll has to start on start up. When it doesn't start, I want to diagnose why. One option is that the executable does't exist.

Comment: I believe the point @Johnsyweb is making is that your file is either a .dll or an executable (.exe).. An .exe file can be loaded and run on startup directly, a .dll will be loaded and code executed through another process - so the kind of file it is will affect how you'd go about troubleshooting your problem..

Comment: Executables aren't always registered. The closes to a registration is the AppPaths feature. Your question suggests you are confused about how Windows starts prcesses. You need to try to improve the question because it cannot be answered at present.

Comment: In particular, is the file you're trying to run a `.dll` file as per the title or an `.exe` file as per the question?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are looking for [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/):

> Dependency Walker detects many common application problems such as missing modules, invalid modules, import/export mismatches, circular dependency errors, mismatched machine types of modules, and module initialization failures.

You can download a copy from http://www.dependencywalker.com/

> Dependency Walker is completely free to use. However, you may not profit from the distribution of it, nor may you bundle it with another product.

If you open your `.EXE` file in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), you'll see a hierarchical tree diagram of all dependent modules (DLLs). Missing DLLs are displayed in red (I think, it has been some years since I last used the tool).

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to run regedit and to find for the dll name through the registry. 
Just F3 (find next) till you find a value of the dll that is a path. It works every time

Answer (score 1):

If this is an automation component you should be able to find the file path under the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\uuid\LocalServer32`, where `uuid` is the uuid of the relevant component. If the component resides within a .dll, rather than an .exe, it will likely be under the `\InProcServer32` rather than `\LocalServer32` key. (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details).